# Installing Wireless Card no GUI: Failed

Tags: ndiswrapper

I installed Ubunutu 12.04 no GUI. The release info is as follows:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS
Release:        12.04
Codename:       precise
```

I custom installed Ubuntu Server in parts following The Perfect Server - Ubuntu 12.04 LTS instructions. Everything works great using eth0, but i have some difficulties with the installation and configuration of the wlan0. My wireless card is Linksys WPC600N Dual Band Wireless-N.

Installed following packages:

```
ndiswrapper-common
ndiswrapper-utils-1.9
wireless-tools
```

Downloaded wireless drivers from Linksys website and installed them:

```
ndiswrapper -i bcmwl5.inf
ndiswrapper -l
WARNING: All config files need .conf: /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist, it will be ignored in a future release.
bcmwl5 : driver installed
        device (14E4:4328) present (alternate driver: ssb)
```

I blacklisted std driver:

```
cat /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist
blacklist bcm43xx
```

I manually added ndiswrapper to the **/etc/modules**

I also  manually adjusted my /etc/network/interfaces. The file is as follows:

My current Network Information is as follows:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback


auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static

        address          192.168.14.223
        netmask          255.255.255.0
        network          192.168.14.0
        broadcast        192.168.14.255
        gateway          192.168.14.84
        dns-nameservers  8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4


iface wlan0 inet static

        address         192.168.14.222
        netmask         255.255.255.0
        network         192.168.14.0
        broadcast       192.168.14.255
        gateway         192.168.14.84
        dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
        wpa-psk         {NETWORK PASSWORD}
        wpa-ssid        {SSID}
```

---

**lspci | grep Network**

```
02:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4321 802.11a/b/g/n (rev 01)
```

---

```
lspci -vvnn

00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RS100 Host Bridge [1002:cab0] (rev 13)
  Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
  Status: Cap+ 66MHz+ UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
  Latency: 32
  Region 0: Memory at d4000000 (32-bit, prefetchable) [size=64M]
  Region 1: Memory at d0400000 (32-bit, prefetchable) [size=4K]
  Region 2: I/O ports at 8090 [disabled] [size=4]
  Capabilities: [a0] AGP version 2.0
    Status: RQ=16 Iso- ArqSz=0 Cal=0 SBA+ ITACoh- GART64- HTrans- 64bit- FW+ AGP3- Rate=x1,x2,x4
    Command: RQ=1 ArqSz=0 Cal=0 SBA+ AGP+ GART64- 64bit- FW- Rate=x4
  Kernel driver in use: agpgart-ati
  Kernel modules: ati-agp

00:01.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RS100 AGP Bridge [1002:700f] (rev 01) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
  Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
  Status: Cap- 66MHz+ UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
  Latency: 99
  Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=68
  I/O behind bridge: 00009000-00009fff
  Memory behind bridge: d0100000-d01fffff
  Prefetchable memory behind bridge: e0000000-efffffff
  Secondary status: 66MHz+ FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- <SERR- <PERR-
  BridgeCtl: Parity- SERR- NoISA+ VGA+ MAbort- >Reset- FastB2B-
    PriDiscTmr- SecDiscTmr- DiscTmrStat- DiscTmrSERREn-
  Kernel modules: shpchp

00:02.0 USB controller [0c03]: ULi Electronics Inc. USB 1.1 Controller [10b9:5237] (rev 03) (prog-if 10 [OHCI])
  Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Pavilion ze4400 builtin USB [103c:0024]
  Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV+ VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
  Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
  Latency: 64 (20000ns max)
  Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 10
  Region 0: Memory at d0000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
  Capabilities: [60] Power Management version 2
    Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1- D2- AuxCurrent=0mA PME(D0-,D1-,D2-,D3hot-,D3cold+)
    Status: D0 NoSoftRst- PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
  Kernel driver in use: ohci_hcd

00:06.0 Multimedia audio controller [0401]: ULi Electronics Inc. M5451 PCI AC-Link Controller Audio Device [10b9:5451] (rev 02)
  Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Pavilion ze4400 builtin Audio [103c:0024]
  Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
  Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR+ <PERR+ INTx-
  Latency: 64 (500ns min, 6000ns max)
  Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 5
  Region 0: I/O ports at 8400 [size=256]
  Region 1: Memory at d0001000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
  Capabilities: [dc] Power Management version 2
    Flags: PMEClk- DSI+ D1+ D2+ AuxCurrent=0mA PME(D0-,D1-,D2+,D3hot+,D3cold+)
    Status: D0 NoSoftRst- PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
  Kernel driver in use: snd_ali5451
  Kernel modules: snd-ali5451

00:07.0 ISA bridge [0601]: ULi Electronics Inc. M1533/M1535/M1543 PCI to ISA Bridge [Aladdin IV/V/V+] [10b9:1533]
  Subsystem: ULi Electronics Inc. ALi M1533 Aladdin IV/V ISA Bridge [10b9:1533]
  Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle+ MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
  Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
  Latency: 0
  Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 1
    Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1- D2- AuxCurrent=0mA PME(D0-,D1-,D2-,D3hot-,D3cold-)
    Status: D0 NoSoftRst- PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
  Kernel modules: alim7101_wdt, alim1535_wdt

00:08.0 Modem [0703]: ULi Electronics Inc. M5457 AC'97 Modem Controller [10b9:5457] (prog-if 00 [Generic])
  Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Pavilion ze4400 builtin Modem Device [103c:0024]
  Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster- SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
  Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
  Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 3
  Region 0: Memory at d0002000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
  Region 1: I/O ports at 8800 [size=256]
  Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 2
    Flags: PMEClk- DSI+ D1- D2- AuxCurrent=0mA PME(D0-,D1-,D2-,D3hot+,D3cold+)
    Status: D0 NoSoftRst- PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-

00:0a.0 CardBus bridge [0607]: O2 Micro, Inc. OZ601/6912/711E0 CardBus/SmartCardBus Controller [1217:6972]
  Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping+ SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
  Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=slow >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
  Latency: 168
  Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 11
  Region 0: Memory at 2c000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
  Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=05, sec-latency=176
  Memory window 0: 34000000-37fff000 (prefetchable)
  Memory window 1: 30000000-33fff000
  I/O window 0: 00001400-000014ff
  I/O window 1: 00001000-000010ff
  BridgeCtl: Parity- SERR- ISA- VGA- MAbort- >Reset- 16bInt- PostWrite+
  16-bit legacy interface ports at 0001
  Kernel driver in use: yenta_cardbus
  Kernel modules: yenta_socket

00:10.0 IDE interface [0101]: ULi Electronics Inc. M5229 IDE [10b9:5229] (rev c4) (prog-if b0)
  Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Pavilion ze4400 builtin IDE [103c:0024]
  Control: I/O+ Mem- BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
  Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
  Latency: 32 (500ns min, 1000ns max)
  Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 0
  Region 0: [virtual] Memory at 000001f0 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8]
  Region 1: [virtual] Memory at 000003f0 (type 3, non-prefetchable) [size=1]
  Region 2: [virtual] Memory at 00000170 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8]
  Region 3: [virtual] Memory at 00000370 (type 3, non-prefetchable) [size=1]
  Region 4: I/O ports at 8080 [size=16]
  Capabilities: [60] Power Management version 2
    Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1- D2- AuxCurrent=0mA PME(D0-,D1-,D2-,D3hot-,D3cold-)
    Status: D0 NoSoftRst- PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
  Kernel driver in use: pata_ali
  Kernel modules: pata_ali

00:11.0 Bridge [0680]: ULi Electronics Inc. M7101 Power Management Controller [PMU] [10b9:7101]
  Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Pavilion ze4400 [103c:0024]
  Control: I/O- Mem- BusMaster- SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
  Status: Cap- 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
  Kernel driver in use: ali1535_smbus
  Kernel modules: alim7101_wdt, i2c-ali15x3, i2c-ali1535

00:12.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: National Semiconductor Corporation DP83815 (MacPhyter) Ethernet Controller [100b:0020]
  Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Pavilion ze4400 builtin Network [103c:0024]
  Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
  Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
  Latency: 90 (2750ns min, 13000ns max)
  Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 11
  Region 0: I/O ports at 8c00 [size=256]
  Region 1: Memory at d0003000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
  [virtual] Expansion ROM at 2c010000 [disabled] [size=64K]
  Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 2
    Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1+ D2+ AuxCurrent=320mA PME(D0+,D1+,D2+,D3hot+,D3cold+)
    Status: D0 NoSoftRst- PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME+
  Kernel driver in use: natsemi
  Kernel modules: natsemi

01:05.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RS100 [Radeon IGP 320M] [1002:4336] (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
  Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Pavilion ze4400 builtin Video [103c:0024]
  Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping+ SERR- FastB2B+ DisINTx-
  Status: Cap+ 66MHz+ UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
  Latency: 66 (2000ns min), Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
  Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 10
  Region 0: Memory at e0000000 (32-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
  Region 1: I/O ports at 9000 [size=256]
  Region 2: Memory at d0100000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
  [virtual] Expansion ROM at d0120000 [disabled] [size=128K]
  Capabilities: [58] AGP version 2.0
    Status: RQ=48 Iso- ArqSz=0 Cal=0 SBA+ ITACoh- GART64- HTrans- 64bit- FW- AGP3- Rate=x1,x2,x4
    Command: RQ=16 ArqSz=0 Cal=0 SBA+ AGP+ GART64- 64bit- FW- Rate=x4
  Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 2
    Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1+ D2+ AuxCurrent=0mA PME(D0-,D1-,D2-,D3hot-,D3cold-)
    Status: D0 NoSoftRst- PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
  Kernel driver in use: radeon
  Kernel modules: radeon, radeonfb

02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4321 802.11a/b/g/n [14e4:4328] (rev 01)
  Subsystem: Linksys WPC600N v1 802.11a/b/g/n Wireless-N CardBus Adapter [1737:0066]
  Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
  Status: Cap- 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
  Latency: 64
  Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 11
  Region 0: Memory at 30000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
  Kernel driver in use: b43-pci-bridge
  Kernel modules: ssb
```

---

**ip link**

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16436 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0d:9d:5b:a5:f7 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:1e:e5:aa:b9:c5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

---

**iwconfig**

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bg  ESSID:off/any
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=0 dBm
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:on

eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

---

when i try to start wlan0 i get following message:

**ifup wlan0**

```
wpa_supplicant: /sbin/wpa_supplicant daemon failed to start
run-parts: /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/wpasupplicant exited with return code 1
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Failed to bring up wlan0.
```

I also tried:

**ip link set wlan0 up**

```
RTNETLINK answers: No such file or directory
```

**sudo modprobe -r ndiswrapper**

```
WARNING: All config files need .conf: /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist, it will be ignored in a future release.
FATAL: Module ndiswrapper not found.
```

**modprobe ndiswrapper**

```
WARNING: All config files need .conf: /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist, it will be ignored in a future release.
FATAL: Module ndiswrapper not found.
```

I am new to Linux environment. I looked all over the place reading through documentation but was not able to figure out where i failed to properly configure or install package. Any help will be greatly appreciated.